# What happens if I don't pass the context argument to the super key in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-class

So, I've seen many developers/sites/code/examples passing only `props` to the parent class with the `super` keyword, like this :

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { someState: '' };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1> Hello {this.props.name} </h1>
    );
  }
}
```

But actually, the second argument passed to a component class is the `context` and many developers/sites/code/examples don't pass it to the parent, but from my point of view it should always be passed:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = { someState: '' };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1> Hello {this.props.name} </h1>
    );
  }
}
```

So my question is:

#### Does it affect not passing the context to the parent object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `context` object will not be passed to your component unless you define `contextTypes`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#referencing-context-in-lifecycle-methods).

Therefore, in your example, React will never pass the `context` object in, so there's no point passing it down to the super constructor. You *can* do it if you'd like, but it'll be functionally equivalent to not doing so.

Comment: But having Higher order components (HOC), might or might not inject context into the passed component like `redux`, right?

Comment: A HOC generally extracts data from the context and passes it on as props. It has access to the context because it specifies its contextTypes. Unless a component does so, it cannot access the context.

Comment: @JoseAPL: See Timo's comment, explained it better than I was going to :) Redux uses context to access the store, but it passes the data from the context to your component via props. Passing the context object directly to a child component is probably not a good idea.

Comment: @JoseAPL: The beauty of open source - [here's where the Redux HOC grabs the store from the context](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/connectAdvanced.js#L122), and [here's where it passes the subscribed data down as props](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/connectAdvanced.js#L256).

Comment: I see, thank you guys, I will mark this answer as correct

Comment: @JoseAPL: Thanks :)